# Can I draw with Java Graphics2D simultaneously on one panel using multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics, graphics2d

I'm writing a plotting program and I've run into a problem where if the number of plotted lines is too big, the program becomes laggy and unresponsive. 
Is it possible to split the datapoints into multiple smaller groups and plot them simultanously onto one JPanel using a thread for each group?

Comment: Short answer  - no.  Long answer would involve using a backing buffer of some kind onto which the threads can draw independently of the UI and when done, the buffer could be painted to the UI

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. ON windows, for example, only the main thread is allowed to draw graphics in response to the WM_PAINT message, must start with a call to BeginPaint and must end with EndPaint. The rest is ignored or not reliably taken into account. Java cannot go across this kind of OS rules.